# Low beams are acting weird

Tags: ford, headlight

I have a 1991 Ford Explorer.

Today I fired it up and the low beams weren't working so I opened the hood while they were still not working. My girl call me so I slammed the hood and BAM it started working.

I don't know where to look and need help to fix it. Please help.

Comment: It's probably a bad contact. Start with the connectors to headlights themselves and go from there. If it's tough to find a multimeter can help you narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

The prime suspects here would be:

- a low-beam relay that is sticking
- a bad contact at the light switch/stalk
- break in the low-beam wiring

I'd start with the relay since it is the easiest to test.

Comment: Another possibility is a bad ground at the headlight.